# Is there a way to run the same test on multiple browsers using Protractor, with a few seconds delay in between?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor, angular-test

I am trying to run my test on multiple browser instances, which I do using multiCapabilities, but I would like to do this with a few seconds delay between, so one starts a little after the other. How can I do this without duplicating the test and adding browser.sleep?

Comment: How about add sleep in jasmine's `beforeEach()` hook?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to wait when the test are running parallely and independently in different browsers?
However if your requirement is still to wait for some time before starting the other browser tests you can add different sleep for different browsers in before() or beforeAll() hook depending upon which test runner you are using, jasmine or mocha.
And when you add these sleeps add those in if conditions

If browsername is chrome then wait for 2 sec 
If browsername is firefox then wait for 4 sec
If browsername is safari then wait for 6 sec

PS: Cant write the indentated code here as I am typing from mobile browser but if you need these if conditions I can do it.

Also, If you dont know how you can read browserName on which tests are running here please let me know.